Does KeyHolder keep order of rows in batch insert?
I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate to insert a batch of rows to the the database. Third parameter of the method is a KeyHolder instance that I can use to retrieve the list of generated keys via the KeyHolder.getKeyList() method.
My question is: does the order of values in the result of getKeyList() correspond to the order of rows inserted via batchUpdate()?
(For example, if I am inserting rows A, B, C in a batch, then is it guaranteed that getKeyList() returns A.id, B.id, C.id in this order? Therefore, can I just zip the two lists together to know which inserted entry received which generated key?)

First off to answer your question, if unsure, you should just loop through the values quick sorting them as needed. Don't want to rely on something outside your control unless you know for a fact of how it works and there is some type of documentation or something expressing this guarantee. If this is a bottle neck, then looking at a db like MarkLogic might be worth it. Don't see it being one though.
Second, when using generated IDs, I believe they should be arbitrary for the applications using them, since it can be re-indexed and changed at any time. So applications shouldn't use this indexes for stability reasons. If insertion time is important for querying, then a field should be added to be queried on and not based on the order in the db. Usually you would have a created, and modified timestamp since if the db is done it could go to another system until it is back up effecting the time as well.
If ID is important than create an actual field for it that is meaningful and won't change under your application.

Looked a bit into the source code and it seems, yes they are collected as generated. See AbstractJdbcInsert#executeInsertAndReturnKeyHolderInternal and JdbcTemplate#storeGeneratedKeys
private void storeGeneratedKeys(KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder, PreparedStatement ps, int rowsExpected)
    throws SQLException {

    List<Map<String, Object>> generatedKeys = generatedKeyHolder.getKeyList();
    ResultSet keys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (keys != null) {
        try {
            RowMapperResultSetExtractor<Map<String, Object>> rse =
                new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<>(getColumnMapRowMapper(), rowsExpected);
            generatedKeys.addAll(result(rse.extractData(keys))); // ordered add
        }
        finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(keys);
        }
    }
}


Yes, the KeyHolder in Spring JDBC preserves the order of rows when performing a batch insert operation. The keys returned in the KeyHolder will correspond to the rows in the same order they were inserted in the batch.

do you have any source to back up your claim?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
